# doctrine 2 findby function , get keys and values

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, findby

can i get the keys and values dynamically.

in php, you would: `foreach ($array  as $key  => $value)`

but you can do this for :

```
$this->_em->getRepository('Members')->findBy(array('id' =>5));
```

any way to get the keys from this with their values..?

i can do this by turning it into an array and extract it but i wouldnt get any association results inside the array ..

i want to do this as i want to be able to extract all properties and values of this object and extract all other objects within it too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ih had the same issue as you now have and after some research i just found a solution which you might be interested.what you need is an associative array of keys/values and not an object.findBy()method only returns entity OBJECT.so you will need to use DQL(doctrine query language).

```
//create a QueryBuilder instance
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->add('select', 'a')
//enter the table you want to query
->add('from', 'Members a')
->add('where', 'a.id = :id')
//order by username if you like
//->add('orderBy', 'a.username ASC')
//find a row with id=5
->setParameter('id', '5');
query = $qb->getQuery();
//if you dont put 3 or Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY inside getResult() an object is returned and if you put 3 an array is returned
$accounts = $query->getResult(3);
```

from doctrine documentation:

> 13.7.4. Hydration Modes
>
> Each of the Hydration Modes makes assumptions about how the result is
>   returned to user land. You should know about all the details to make
>   best use of the different result formats:
>
> The constants for the different hydration modes are:
>   Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT 
>   Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY 
>   Query::HYDRATE_SCALAR
>   Query::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR

To learn more about 'The Query Builder' please refer to [doctrine2 documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/query-builder.html#the-querybuilder)

**Update:**
To fetch associated Entities you will need to define fetch joins.Here is an example provided in [doctrine documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/tutorials/getting-started-xml-edition.html#array-hydration-of-the-bug-list):

```
$dql = "SELECT b, e, r, p FROM Bug b JOIN b.engineer e ".
   "JOIN b.reporter r JOIN b.products p ORDER BY b.created DESC";
$query = $entityManager->createQuery($dql);
$bugs = $query->getArrayResult();

foreach ($bugs AS $bug) {
  echo $bug['description'] . " - " . $bug['created']->format('d.m.Y')."\n";
  echo "    Reported by: ".$bug['reporter']['name']."\n";
  echo "    Assigned to: ".$bug['engineer']['name']."\n";
foreach($bug['products'] AS $product) {
  echo "    Platform: ".$product['name']."\n";}
  echo "\n";}
```

The code mentioned above will fetch your entities as array of arrays and you can do whatever you want with $keys and $values.
Hope this helps...

Comment: yep this good but have you got a solution to get all associatIon object within the results?  this is only pulling the column values only...

Comment: You will need to use Fetch Joins in your DQL query to fetch other tables data.this is how lazy loading works.DQL is not association aware.In Doctrine 2 is an ORM and we need to define many queries explicitly and doctrine 2 hardens many tasks reagrding setting and getting values automatically...

Comment: @afterburner I am fetching my data using HYDRATE_OBJECT for multiple left joins, thus it returns multiple object arrays for each entity, the problem I am getting is how to know which object array is of which entity. Any suggestions ?